# Linking of css file using link tag not working in server

Tags: php, html, css, hyperlink

my folder structure is like

```
   devlopment{
     core{index.php}
     css{index.css}
   }
```

My document root is devlopment/core/ in apache document root
when i try to link css using link tag my path is ../css/index.css that is not working what sholud i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a browser resolves a relative URL, it can't go beyond the first `/` in the path (i.e. the document root). It can only ask for files which have a URL.

Since you have put the CSS outside the document root, the CSS doesn't have a URL.

You need to move it somewhere where it does have a URL (i.e. inside the document root) and then use that URL in your `<link>`.

Comment: then how to include css file from outlise of document root using link tag ?

Comment: If you **really** want to too that, then look up the `Alias` configuration directive… but there is rarely a reason to do that, especially when your use case is as simple as this appears. Do what I recommended in this answer instead.